# I perform an S3 copy between accounts and when I download from the destination I get an Access Denied error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am copying a large bucket from one AWS account to another. I have everything set up correctly so the copying between the accounts is working properly.

The problem is if I try to download any of the files from the destination bucket in the destination account I get the following error -

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>WTNVZ8GP461HF</RequestId>
<HostId>+huzz+Fzls7SplZPZHCWLXqfcGWQBHccKEvcL96raIw3g0f+cHzqQyvpTNhHxCgJXER4Ahs=</HostId>
</Error>
```

I am doing the download from the AWS S3 dashboard in the destination account.The account I am using has admin privileges.

Both the original bucket and destination bucket are encrypted.

Do I have to change ownership of bring over the encryption key from the source or can I convert it to work in the destination?

Below is the copy command I used. What command should i have used to avoid this in the first place?

```
aws s3 cp s3://dbtable-storage/288/ s3://test-destination/288/ --recursive --exclude '
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding acl to have bucket owner full control over the object

```
--acl bucket-owner-full-control
```

If it still errors out, check if the object is encrypted, source bucket may be enabled with encryption in which case depending on the type of SSE, respective option like --sse or --sse-c-copy-source or similar has to be used

Comment: Yes the source bucket is encrypted. So is this the correct copy command             --------- - 
"aws s3 sync s3://dbtable-storage-meridian/288/ s3://test-destination/288/ --exclude 'formdatasnapshots/*'  --region us-east-1 --ssw-s-copy-source".-----------
  

                Is there a way to convert what has already been copied?

Comment: No, you need to copy again